# Make dropdown from li elements

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make dropdown menu from three `li` elements. Active `li` element gets class `current_lang` and it should work as a parent which can be clicked to open dropdown. Dropdown should also work with mobile devices.

Any ideas/help how to make dropdown from this kind of `ul` list?

```
<ul class="language_switch">
<li><a href="#">de</a></li>
<li class="current_lang"><a href="#">en</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ch</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j6gt8go9/)

Comment: Check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769172/css-drop-down-menu-cross-browser
Solved answer point has a post, which might be helpful - http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/centered-dropdown-menus

Comment: I don't see how that link helps me on this, sorry.

Comment: Maybe you should switch to using a `<select>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `selectbox` with `dropdown` using `<ul> & <li>` elements, with functionality.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectbox').on('click', function(){
        var select = $('.select'); 
        select.toggleClass('active');
        $('.options li span').on('click', function(){
            var pk = $(this).closest('li').find('i').first().text();
   $(this).closest('.options').find('span').show(); // - $(this).closest('.options').find('span').removeClass('active');
            $(this).hide(); // - $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.selected').text($(this).html());
            select.toggleClass('hidden');
            $('.header').find('input[name=category]').val(pk);
        })
    });
})
```

```css
.selectbox {
 position:relative; 
 height: auto; 
 width: 270px; 
 font-weight: bold;
 }
.select {
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
 padding:0 5px;
 border:4px solid black;
 background: grey;
 border-radius:13px;
 }
.select.active {
 padding:0 5px 5px;
 z-index:2;
 background: grey;
 border: 4px solid black;
 box-shadow:0 0 13px orange;
 }
.select.hidden {
 display:block;
}
.select div {display:none;}
.select.active div {display:block;}
.select .header {
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 cursor:pointer;
 padding:5px 0;
 }
.select .selected {
 line-height:25px;
 display:block;
 color: white;
 }
.select i {
 position: absolute;
 right:0;
 top:11px;
 width:14px;
 height:6px;
 }
.select.active i {background-position:0 -18px;}
.select .options {max-height:200px; overflow:auto;}
.options i {display:none;}
.select ul {list-style-type:none;}
.select ul li {
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 margin-top:2px;
 }
.select ul li span {
 display:inline-block;
 line-height:1;
 color:#5d5d5d;
 cursor:pointer;
 position:relative;
 color:white;
 }
.select ul li span:hover, .select ul li span.active {color:orange;left:3px;}
.select ul li span.active {font-weight:bold;}
.select li ul {margin-left:10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectbox">
    <div class="select">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="selected">Select</div>
            <i></i>
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="category">
        </div>
        <div class="options">
             <ul>
                <li><i>1</i><span>OPTION 1</span></li>
                <li><i>2</i><span>OPTION 2</span></li>
                <li><i>3</i><span>OPTION 3</span></li>
                <li><i>4</i><span>OPTION 4</span></li>
    <li><i>5</i><span>OPTION 5</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```